# Portable way to pass file descriptor between different processes

Tags: unix, fork, share, file-descriptor

On most UNIX systems passing an open file between processes can be easily done for child/parent processes by fork(); however I need to share a fd "after" the child was already forked.

I've found some [webpages](http://www.regatta.cs.msu.su/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/progcomc/skt_comms.htm) telling me that sendmsg() may work for arbitary processes; but that seems very OS dependent and complex. The [portlisten](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000292.html) seems like the best example I can find, but I'd prefer a good wrapper library like libevent that hides all the magic of kqueue, pool, ....

Does anyone know if there's some library (and portable way) to do this?

Comment: Search for "File Descriptor Passing" on [Demystifying Unix Domain Sockets](http://www.techdeviancy.com/uds.html)

Answer (score 18):

Your best bet is to try sending the file descriptor over a Unix domain socket. This is described in Stephens, and in a few places on the web, but I can dig up code for you if you ask nicely.

This will be pretty portable these days; a lot of the things considered "non-portable" way back when (such as `mmap`!) are extremely common now. If you need to be more portable than "most systems these days," you've got a lot of interesting issues ahead of you, but possibly if you tell us more about what you're doing and what platforms you're working on (perhaps non-Unix POSIX platforms?) we might be able to help out.

Comment: I still have a question in using the sendmsg(). I thought putting domain socket as the first parameter is enough, but seems like I still have to fill the msghdr.msg_name as the sockaddr_un of the domain socket - why? anyway to prevent it?

Answer (score 13):

There is a Unix domain socket-based mechanism for transferring file descriptors (such as sockets - which cannot be memory mapped, of course) between processes - using the `sendmsg()` system call.

You can find more in [Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) (as mentioned by Curt Sampson), and also at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

You can find a much more recent question with working code at [Sending file descriptor by Linux socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket/).