# What does Python multirpocessing.reduction do internally?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I found Python multiprocessing.reduction module while suffering from sharing a file descriptor between processes in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989823/how-to-pass-file-descriptors-from-parent-to-child-in-python).

My question is, what does reduction module do internally to share the file descriptor between processes.(`reduce_handle()`, `rebuild_handle()` method)

Could you explain in detail?

```
#reduction.py
def reduce_handle(handle):
    if Popen.thread_is_spawning():
        return (None, Popen.duplicate_for_child(handle), True)
    dup_handle = duplicate(handle)
    _cache.add(dup_handle)
    sub_debug('reducing handle %d', handle)
    return (_get_listener().address, dup_handle, False)

def rebuild_handle(pickled_data):
    address, handle, inherited = pickled_data
    if inherited:
        return handle
    sub_debug('rebuilding handle %d', handle)
    conn = Client(address, authkey=current_process().authkey)
    conn.send((handle, os.getpid()))
    new_handle = recv_handle(conn)
    conn.close()
    return new_handle
```