# Websockets - passing-off open connection to another server?

Tags: network-programming, websocket, scalability

Situation: Two web servers, and a browser client.  The client has an open websockets connection with Server A.  Server A decides that this client should really be serviced by Server B.

**I would like to know if there is any established technique for performing this hand-over?**

It would be great if this could happen as invisibly as possible for my client side code - but I haven't come across any feature which would allow this.

Best I have come up with so far is Server A sending a 'you should really deal with Server X' message, client closing the WS session and then sending some http request which will get routed to the correct server, and upgraded to WS.  I can see the presense of load balancers making this complicatied though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From a programming point of view, the socket connection is treated as an open file handle, and that's what you are trying to pass along. For that, I would check out the question "[Portable way to pass file descriptor between different processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909064/portable-way-to-pass-file-descriptor-between-different-processes)" for a handful of methods.

But if you are not writing your own web server, and are looking for an off-the-shelf method for Apache, etc, this probably won't help you much.

Comment: I'm using Node, so can easily mod the ws server implementation I'm using if neccessary.