# What happens when a lot of processes open the same special file?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, drivers

For example , I have two processes A and B that try to open a special file (`/dev/example`) . The driver has an open method that initializes a structure (`struct c`) and passes it to   `filp->private_data` . When afterwards process B opens the same special file , what happens If I understand correct is that we will have two instances of struct file (two filp pointers that point to the same struct file). Is the open method going to initialize `struct C` again and pass it to `filp->private_data` and what will happen to the one process A initialized ?

Comment: What function are you using to open it?

Comment: with `open()` . Would different functions have different results?

Comment: I don't think so, it appears that `open` is a wrapper around a system call, I was mostly wondering what documentation to look for.

Comment: I suppose that would depend quite a bit on how the driver is actually implemented. In some cases, it would make sense to initialize a single struct and return that to every caller to `open()`. In others, it would make sense to generate a unique struct for every user. There's no way to tell which is appropriate in this case without more information on the driver (probably including code)...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I know , no one returns any struct to any caller. Each file has a specific struct file that represents it and it is passed to any function that operates on the file . The question is general and not about a specific driver .

Comment: If using `O_APPEND` with `fopen()` both processes could write to the file at the same file I believe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When afterwards process B opens the same special file , what happens
> If I understand correct is that we will have two instances of struct
> file (two filp pointers that point to the same struct file).

This is wrong. Every `open(2)` is matched with one `struct file`. Quoting from [LDD3/Chapter3](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf) :

> The file structure represents an open file. (It is not specific to
> device drivers; every open file in the system has an associated struct
> file in kernel space.) It is created by the kernel on open and is
> passed to any function that operates on the file, until the last
> close. After all instances of the file are closed, the kernel releases
> the data structure.

For two processes to share the same `struct file`, they have to have acquired their respective file descriptor via the same `open(2)` system call. This would mean that they either have a parent-child relationship (parent issues `open(2)`, then `fork(2)`s the child, so that the returned file descriptor will be inherited from the parent to the child), or they could be pthreads that access the same file descriptor.

In your case, assuming that processes `A` and `B` do not have a parent-child relationship, they issue a separate `open(2)` system call each. Therefore, they are associated with a different `struct file` each. As a result, each of them is expected to allocate, initialize and store (in its `filp->private_data`) a distinct `struct C`.

What they do always share (and possibly confused you) is the [`struct inode`](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf), which refers to the special file.

---

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comments (by @twalberg), this is indeed highly-dependent on the driver. In general, `filp->private_data` is part of Linux kernel's driver API to *allow* **separate state** per `open(2)`. However, depending on the driver, sometimes it might indeed be sensible to associate multiple different `struct file`s to the same stored state instead.

Comment: "For two processes to share the same `struct file`, they have to have a parent-child relationship" — or they used FD passing over a UNIX domain socket. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/909064/149341