# share a socket with a previously forked child

Tags: c, unix, process, file-descriptor

I've got a server with a number of worker processes forked initially with the server setup. The sever accepts connections, and must pass the descriptor to a worker.

What's an easiest way that I could later on share the socket descriptor of a client's connection with a worker?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket/ for a way to send an open file descriptor to another process.  Other examples can be found via Google search:  https://www.google.com/search?q=sendfd

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unix Network Programming reference really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to run workers with specific port range and use [socketpair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) to share the socket descriptor from another port. Also you can block those worker ports for external communication for the sake of good security pratices.