# How recvmsg() control messages into stack buffer without violating strict aliasing?

Tags: c, posix

When passing file descriptors over Unix domain sockets, control messages at level `SOL_SOCKET` of type `SCM_RIGHTS` are used.

Control messages are read and written using the macros `CMSG_FIRSTHDR`, `CMSG_NXTHDR` and `CMSG_DATA`. They take alignment issues into account. Depending on the operating system and libc implementation, they cast pointers and dereference the result either in the same or a different translation unit. They also return such pointers and the calling code typically dereferences them.

As a result, using a simple stack-allocated `char buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))]` as a control message buffer will violate strict-aliasing as the buffer may only be accessed using lvalues of type `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` or qualified versions of those. (On some platforms, the buffer might also not be suitably aligned, but the amd64 calling conventions appear to guarantee this because the buffer is large enough.)

An obviously correct fix is to allocate the control message buffer using `calloc()`, which provides suitably aligned memory without an effective type. However, I would like to avoid making the program less efficient.

In https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libopenbsd/imsg.c?revision=292023&view=markup I found a different approach where the stack buffer is of type `union { struct cmsghdr hdr; char buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))]; }`, but I don't know whether that is correct. I guess it helps that `struct cmsghdr` has a field of type `int`.

Extra question: how to do this in C++ given that C++ has different rules about (among other things) unions than C?

Comment: I suspect POSIX requires C implementations to align structures so that this isn't a problem.

Comment: @Barmar [POSIX doesn't appear to address alignment in for this usage at all](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html).  Even documents such as [RFC 2292](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2292.txt) assume it's something provided (or not...) by the implementation.  And [the Linux `cmsg` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) uses the same `union` construct to force proper alignment that's mentioned in the question.

Comment: (cont) Note also there's quite a discussion involving alignment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket