# Duplicate Windows sockets between unrelated processes

Tags: c, winapi, winsock2

I'm using C and Winsock2 for my learning project.

I have some questions that I hope some one can confirm.

Let say I have 2 unrelated processes, process A and process B ( without using `CreateProcess` ). By unrelated I mean it's not parent and child.

**1)**

Is it possible in Windows to Accept a socket in process A and pass it to process B if they are unrelated?

**2)**

I guess i have to use `WSADuplicateSocket`? but that only works for related processes?

I hope someone can explain and confirm the above..

Comment: When you say "pass that", what is "that"?

Comment: to pass the socket handle :)

Comment: Unix systems support [sending sockets and other file descriptors via `AF_UNIX` sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003921/sending-file-descriptor-by-linux-socket).  Windows [now supports `AF_UNIX` sockets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/), but I don't know if that includes sending sockets between processes.

Comment: I know about UNIX, sadly you can't pass sockets with AF_UNIX in Windows

Comment: Why would would `WSADuplicateSocket` only work for *"related"* processes, and what sort of relationship do you have in mind?

Comment: @IInspectable `WSADuplicateSocket` requires the original socket in order to duplicate it.  That socket only exists in that one process (and maybe child processes).  The fundamental problem is how to send that socket to another otherwise-unrelated process.

Comment: I'm revisiting a old issue of mine. I remember that WSADuplicateSocket only worked if  process A created  process B ( like forking)..

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes you get my issue..

Comment: @sakdkjkjjjsdjds [DuplicateHandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN) probably goes a long way to solving your problem.  From looking at that, if Process A has a handle to Process B, Process A then uses `DuplciateHandle()` to create a new socket handle in Process B.  Then Process A has to get the new handle *value* to Process B somehow.

Comment: Big complain to Microsoft for not supporting ancillary data in the Windows unix socket implementation... - and a big thanks to you @AndrewHenle for giving me hope. I will try that.. and find way with it

Comment: @AndrewHenle it says " [in] bInheritHandle

A variable that indicates whether the handle is inheritable. If TRUE, the duplicate handle can be inherited by new processes created by the target process. If FALSE, the new handle cannot be inherited. " look like only will work if process B is created by process A or i'm misunderstanding something - or they mean that option is for process B's childs..?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. Parent-child relationships between processes are recorded, but not used for anything interesting. If you `DuplicateHandle` a handle into another process, then the target process can use that handle. `bInheritHandle` limits whether the target process can inherit the handle to another process it creates or not.

Comment: @and Processes need not be related in any way to participate in IPC. You have several options of implementing [IPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

Comment: So you are saying if i run Process A and later Process B - i should be able to use  in Process A WSADuplicateSocket and send the socket to Process B with named pipe even if they are not related ? i'm just trying to confirm if DuplicateHandle is needed at all..

Comment: not exist "related" processes at all

Comment: @sakdkjkjjjsdjds: There are two ways to share handles and sockets between processes.  Inheritance is one (and only works from parent to child).  DuplicateHandle/WSADuplicateSocket is a separate way, independent of inheritance and independent of the parent/child relationship that inheritance requires.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you for explaining that step by step!

Comment: @sakdkjkjjjsdjds "*So you are saying if i run Process A and later Process B - i should be able to use in Process A WSADuplicateSocket and send the socket to Process B with named pipe even if they are not related ?*" - yes. The `WSADuplicateSocket()` documentation *literally* says as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible in Windows to Accept a socket in process A and pass it to process B if they are unrelated?

Yes, via [`WSADuplicateSocket()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketw):

> **The `WSADuplicateSocket` function is used to enable socket sharing between processes.** A source process calls `WSADuplicateSocket` to obtain a special `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure. **It uses some interprocess communications (IPC) mechanism to pass the contents of this structure to a target process**, which in turn uses it in a call to `WSASocket` to obtain a descriptor for the duplicated socket. The special `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure can only be used once by the target process.

> I guess i have to use WSADuplicateSocket?

Yes.

> but that only works for related processes?

No.  It will work fine between any 2 processes, as long as process A knows process B's Process ID, as that is a required parameter of `WSADuplicateSocket()`.

Comment: A quick search for *WSADuplicateSocket* sample([sockdup](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/winsock/sockdup)).