# How to ask a user for "sudo" permission in runtime in Go

Tags: linux, go, console, sudo

In my GO scenario, I have a function that might be called or not. This function has this statement:

```
bpfPath := fmt.Sprintf("/dev/bpf%d", i)
f, err = os.OpenFile(bpfPath, os.O_RDWR, 0666)
```

However, the file `/dev/bpf0` could be opened only with `sudo`.

Is it possible to ask a user for permission for `sudo` only in case when I call to open this file, in runtime?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking: are you trying to know that the error is caused due to a non-root account and report to user so, or are you trying to ask the user to provide permission and then try that part again with other data remained in runtime?

Comment: @leafbebop the second. I want right before opening the file I want to ask a user for sudo.

Comment: You can't add privilege to an already running program. You might try one of two things: restart the program via [`sudo` (or a privileged wrapper program)](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Exec); invoke a helper program (you will likely have to write that for your needs) that passes an opened file descriptor (via a [unix domain socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909064/portable-way-to-pass-file-descriptor-between-different-processes)) to your running program.

Comment: You can't elevate the permissions of a unix process during runtime - even with `sudo`. You can run a sudo subprocess via `cmd.Exec()` - but that process will not be part of your main go program. You could probably `cmd.Exec` `sudo cat /dev/bpf1` and read the process `Stdout` to get the privileged file content. You'll all have to set `NOPASSWD` rules in the `sudoers` file to ensure you don't get password prompted for this particular command (as password submission to a tty will get very tricky).